# Is "set" the default multiplicity?

Tags: alloy

Are these two equivalent:

```
r: A -> B

r: A set -> set B
```

That is, is `set` the default multiplicity?

If yes, then I will quibble with the definition of the arrow operator in the Software Abstractions book. The book says on page 55:

> The arrow product (or just product) p->q of two relations p and q is
>   the relation you get by taking every combination of a tuple from p and
>   a tuple from q and concatenating them.

I interpret that definition to mean the *only* valid instance for p->q is one that has every possible combination of tuples from p with tuples from q. But that's not right (I think). Any instance containing mappings between p and q is valid. For example, on page 56 is this example,

```
Name = {(N0), (N1)}
Addr = {(D0), (D1)}
```

The book says this is a valid relation for Name->Addr

```
{(N0, D0), (N0, D1), (N1, D0), (N1, D1)}
```

But that's not the *only* valid relation, right? For example, this is a valid relation:

```
{(N0, D0), (N1, D1)}
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration r : A->B means r is a subset of A->B. The expression A->B has just one value, which is the cross product of A and B. The declaration results in a set of possible values for r, which would include both the example given in the book that you cite, and the example that you ask about.